# Java JSP get hostname (url) and then redirect if not

Tags: java, jsp

I'm not a jsp developer but i would like to make a small adjustment to a jsp page in some open source software i have.

All i want to do is find out what url i used to get to the page, let's say  https://old.example.com, and if i did then i would like to redirect the user to https://new.example.com, but i don't want to get in a redirect loop obviously...

how would i go about this ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
<% 
    if(request.getRequestURL().toString().equals("https://old.example.com")){    
        String redirectURL = "https://new.example.com"; 
        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
    }
%>
```

And in case you don't prefer java code inside your JSP (which is a bad programming practice), you could try something like this using [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html)

```
<c:if test="${pageContext.request.requestURL == 'https://old.example.com'}">
    <jsp:forward page="https://new.example.com"/>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

looks more like job for controller, not for view.

Edited

But if you really want to, you can try something like this (suppose you use JSTL):

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:if test="${fn:contains(pageContext.request.requestURL, 'localhost')}">
   <c:redirect url="http://google.com"/>
</c:if>
```

Comment: that's fine to me, but what does the structure in jsp look like.... i have a public folder, but no real MVC modeled folders... any idea where i would look to find this controller?

Comment: Tobias, if you have only public jsp pages then you'll probably need to add code like this or scriplets like in other answers to every jsp page you need this behaviour.